# wp_enqueue_script is not loading JS in at all

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Have built a Wordpress theme that is working and tested on one domain, however, when installing the theme to another domain my `wp_enqueue_script` are not showing the `<script>` at all, whilst the `<styles>` are showing in the head.

The code added to the `functions.php` is

```
function core_styles_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'pace-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'scrollbar-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'select-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'switchery-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/switchery/css/switchery.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'pages-icons-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pages/css/pages-icons.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-light-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pages/css/themes/light.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-custom-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pages/css/themes/custom.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts',  '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700,900|Open+Sans:400,600');



wp_enqueue_script( 'feather-icons-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/feather-icons/feather.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'pace-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'mondernizr-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/modernizr.custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'tether-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/tether/js/tether.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-easy-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-easy.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-unveil-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/jquery-unveil/jquery.unveil.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-bez-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/jquery-bez/jquery.bez.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ioslist-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/jquery-ios-list/jquery.ioslist.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'imagesloaded-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-actual-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/jquery-actual/jquery.actual.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-scrollbar-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-sticky-tabs-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/jquery-sticky-tabs/jquery.stickytabs.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-tabs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/bootstrap-collapse/bootstrap-tabcollapse.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'select2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/select2/js/select2.full.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'classie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/classie/classie.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'nav-tabs-url', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'pages-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pages/js/pages.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'core_styles_scripts' );
```

I cannot find fault with the above, but maybe someone else can. Just to re-mention - On one domain the `<scripts>` are added to the `<footer>` and the `<style>` is added to the `<head>` (correct), on the other (new install) it keeps the `<style>` in the `<head>` but the `<script>` are not loading at all. I have tried both installs to zero plugins and just the theme with the same issue. I have tried removing all other functions. I have tried HTTPS and HTTP.

Any help is appreciated. I guarantee it is simple and I am missing something obvious. Also, neither have any errors in debug or firebug.

Comment: It looks ok so I can only ask the obvious questions, just in case :) If they are different servers, maybe one has cached an old version? I presume they both have the same version of WP, PHP, database, jQuery etc? You dont have a child theme on one that's overriding the core_styles_scripts function? If you disable all plugins, and strip out literally everything else but the core_styles_scripts with just one wp_enqueue_script, does it work?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No cached version, this was my immediate thought but not the problem. I have updated both servers to match one another but still the same. Stripped, removed everything from the themes, plugins and still the same issue. Still getting zero errors on either and a total loss of what the issue is. I am just creating a third server and wordpress install.

Comment: Yeah, caching does sound like it would be the most likely cause. Well that's all I have to suggest, sorry!

Comment: I found the problem. It was a plugin that had been cached function that had been commented but was still cached and running on the original setup. Thank you for your time and as much I love caching, it can be a pain!

Comment: Did deactivated all plugins not stop that :) ? Anyway, glad you got it sorted!

Comment: No, it didn't stop that. The original DNS was run through Cloudflare, whilst the others were pointing directly from the servers. A simple switch to making the original site to development mode and emptying the cache started to cause the same issues as my replications. Then I was able to find the issue among my revisions.

Comment: Ah I see... cached cache :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use :: 
add_action('wp_footer', 'core_styles_scripts'); 
instead of 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'core_styles_scripts' );

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't change anything.